# i want to send email to user when the custom taxonomy is changed

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Hello every one i am new to wordpress development.  i am working on a plugin in which i have created a custom post type with the name of application when the user submits a form from the frontend a new application is created with the user data. i have a custom taxonomy in it with the name of application_status. I want to send an email to the user when the admin change the status of the taxonomy like from pending to accepted. I have a general idea how to do it like i can get the new updated value and compare it with the previous value(which is saved in database) and if it is changed i can send the email. So can anybody guide me how can i get the new changed taxonomy value before it is stored so that i can compare it with the previous value.

from some references i have seen the hook

```php
       $this->loader->add_filter( 'transition_post_status', $plugin_admin, 'send_mail_when_status_changed', 10, 3);
```

and the function is

```php
function send_mail_when_status_changed($new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
        if ( 'publish' !== $new_status ||
            $new_status === $old_status ||
            'application' !== get_post_type( $post ) ) {
            return;
        }
    
        // Get the post author data.
        if ( ! $user = get_userdata( $post->post_author ) ) {
            return;
        }
        //check if the taxonomy is changed
        $appstatus='Pending';
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'application_status');
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $appstatus=$term->name; 
        } 
        //donot know how to get compare the value with the changed value

    
        // Compose the email message.
        // $body = sprintf( 'Hey %s, your awesome post has been published! See ,
        //  esc_html( $user->display_name ),
        //  get_permalink( $post )
        // );
    
        // // Now send to the post author.
        // wp_mail( $user->user_email, 'Your post published!', $body );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved, using the hook

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'send_mail_when_status_changed', 10, 3);
```

it passed three parameters to the function `$data,$postarr,$unsanitized_postarr` using them i got the id of the taxonomy which is updated and compared it to the id of the taxonomy saved in the database and act accordingly
for more information visit here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/

here is the function

```php
 function send_mail_when_status_changed($data, $postarr, $unsanitized_postarr   ){
        if($data['post_type']!='application'){ //checking if the post type is application
            return $data;
        }
        $post_ID=!empty($postarr['post_id']) ? $postarr['post_id'] :'';
        //getting the updated taxonomy ID
        $updated_status_ID=!empty($postarr['tax_input']['application_status'][1]) ? $postarr['tax_input']['application_status'][1] : '';//here
        //getting the name of the updated status
        $updated_status_term=get_term($updated_status_ID );
        $updated_status_name=!empty($updated_status_term->name) ?$updated_status_term->name: ''; //here
        $updated_status_name;
        $updated_status_name=strtolower($updated_status_name);
        //getting the id of the post author
        $post_user_id=$data['post_author'];
        //getting the email of the post author
        $user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email',$post_user_id);
        //fethcing the previous taxonomy status ID from the database
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ID, 'application_status');
        $old_status_ID='';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $old_status_ID=$term->term_id; 
        } 
        if($old_status_ID!=$updated_status_ID){
            if($updated_status_name=='accepted'){
                // Email subject"
                $subject = 'Your Application Status';
            
                // Email body
                $message = 'Your Application for the Job was accepted ';
            
                wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
            }else if($updated_status_name=='rejected'){
                // Email subject, "New {post_type_label}"
                $subject = 'Your Application Status';
            
                // Email body
                $message = 'Your Application for the Job was Rejected ';
            
                wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
            }else if($updated_status_name=='pending'){
                // Email subject, "New {post_type_label}"
                $subject = 'Your Application Status';
            
                // Email body
                $message = 'Your Application for the Job was Pending ';
            
                wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pre_post_update` hook to get the new value before the post is saved. This way you can check if the value has changed (old value is still in the database at this point) and do your magic.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/

Comment: ok thanks will try

Comment: can you please tell how can i get the the value of taxonomy from the $data?like i have to use `$data->'taxonomy_name'`? @DeltaG